# Runtime dynamic SQL Server database access by different connection strings

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I've searched the stackoverflow for a long time and didn't find a solution fit my situation, so I asked here.

I have a single asp.net website, and need the web app to access different SQL Server database by the subdomain name.

According to the url request subdomian to determine the access the different database.

> 1. prj1.test.com  prj1--->use the prj1_DB
> 2. prj2.test.com  prj2 use the prj2_DB

I couldn't find a better practice to solve the issue.

My intuition solution:

when the url request coming, get the url subdomain, get the subdomain's db connection string stored in the main db, passing the connection string to the DAL to get the data.

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
DataTable  dt = ProjectObject.GetProjectIndexNotice(new object[] { 0, CurrentProject.DbConnectionString });
```

**ProjectObject.cs**

```
public static DataTable GetProjectIndexNotice(object[] param)
{
   ProjectDLC obj = new ProjectDLC();
   return obj.GetProjectIndexNotice(param);
}
```

**ProjectDAL.cs**

```
public DataTable GetProjectIndexNotice(object[] param)
{
   return base.GetDataTableFromDatabase(param, "NEMP_GetProjectIndexNotice");
}
```

**DALBase.cs**

```
DataBase db = new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase(CurrentProject.DbConnectionString);
```

I want to find a better way to solve this problem.

The solution I using above is:

- get the dbConnectionString from main DB,
- passing it over the **Index.page ->BusinessObject Layer -->DAL Layer**

It's so bad that passing the DB connection string from UI page to the DAL layer.

Any ideas?

**Update 1:**
What I really want is: don't pass the db connection string from UI to DAL layer.

I want to find a solution that don't do pass the db connstr from UI to DAL linearly.

Is there some pattern in asp.net to share some variable for UI layer and DAL Layer?

**Update 2:**
if I stored the project db info in a xml file or in the main db, it looks like this

it's a key-value part for the project. here is the question, I get the values all in the main DB or a xml file. **How I get the key when I need to access the DB in DAL layer**?

in the DAL layer, **how to get the correct key** for the currnet url request?

it's back to the above, pass the key from UI to DAL. that's I want to avoid.

**the real problem is, I can get the key from url request in the UI layer, and I can get the value for that key in the DAL layer. but there is a gap between the two layers, How to conquer this gap?**

Answer (score 1):

If you can **compute** your connection string from a base connection string, then you could do something like this:

- store the base connection string in your `web.config`

  ```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="BaseConnString" 
          connectionString="server=MyServer;database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ```
- load the base connection string into a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` in your code:

  ```
  string baseConnStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["BaseConnString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsBuilder = 
     new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(baseConnStr);
  ```
- now, just define the database you want to connect to, e.g. based on something in your URL

  ```
  scsBuilder.InitialCatalog = "ProjectDatabase" + ........ ;
  ```
- use the resulting complete connection string for your `SqlConnection`:

  ```
  using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(scsBuilder.ConnectionString))
  {
     // do something
  }
  ```

Check out the [MSDN docs on SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

With this approach, you'd store a single "base" connection string in your `web.config` and this wouldn't be changing, and using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, you can safely and efficiently define and "compute" your real, "dynamic" connection strings at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

maybe I can't clearly  described my major question.

The major's question is, Is it appropriate I pass the connection string from the UI to the DAL layer?

I want to find another solution that don't do that like this, such as, find some pattern to do this.

what i want is: don't   pass the db connection string from UI to DAL layer.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding add the connection strings in web.config as:

**Subdomain_connectionString**

Now [read the subdomain](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2488.htm) from Request:

Reading connection string from web.config in your DL:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Subdomain_connectionString].ConnectionString
```

**Update:**

You can also use xml files to store connection string values:

```
<ROOT>
<Project_1>
<IPAddress></IPAddress>
<DBName></DBName>
...
</Project_1>
<Project_2>
....
</ROOT>
```

Anytime a new project is added/removed this xml file would be updated. Use XPath expressions to parse the xml file.

**@Passing Connection string from UI to DAL**: Just try to add the System.web namespace to DAL layer. This would give access to Request object in DAL. Now you can get the subdomain and build the connectionstring in DAL itself. Not sure whether this is a right approach, but might work in your case.

Comment: the problem is we have more than one  hundred sub-project, and the project is dynamically added or deleted. If I stored every project's db-connectionstring in web.conf file, then I need to modify the web.conf file every time when the project changes. 

and in the production environment, we cannot change the web.config file frequently.

Comment: If all your databases are saved on the same server and their names are same as project names then you can use only one main connectionstring in web.config and just change the initial catalog part at runtime.

Comment: our database are not in the same server.
prjA's DB is on the 192.168.20.6
prjB's DB is on the 192.168.20.226

We Stored the Project's db connectstring in the main db, in the projectInfo table, it contains 'projectid','projectcode','prjectDBstring'...
etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot Asseem!

if I maintain a xml file for the projects, but it still need a key to find which project db is going to using for the current url request.

the only idea which I can get is to pass a projectcode from UI to the DAL to get the current project's db connectionstring.

I've search for many places   about two weeks, still couldn't find a better solution to solve the issue.

Comment: In that case the xml file will contain nodes for Subdomain. <Subdomain><ProjectInfo>... <Key>SomeKey</Key>... You can customize the xml format as per your requirements.